# I need to automate to post a skype attachment in skype group using "skpy" python library

Tags: python, python-3.x, skype

`

```
from skpy import Skype, SkypeChats, SkypeGroupChat
sk= Skype("username", "password")
sk.conn
ch = sk.contacts.contact("python automation tests").chat
ch.sendFile(open(r"E:\\qwe.png", "rb"), "qwe.png", image=True
```

[image]
i am trying to post a png file in skype group , it didn't works for me please help me to correct my code

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```py
from skpy import Skype, SkypeChats

skype = Skype("SKYPE_USER", "SKYPE_PASS")

ch = skype.chats[id]
ch.sendFile(img, "file.png", image=True)
```

and if you wish to get group id use :

```py
 skc = SkypeChats(skype)
 print(skc.recent())
```

just look for the group name in printed result and write down group id. it must be sth like :

```
19:f405b330d4eb4e9edh90b037699663a21@thread.skype
```